# How to load values from query to myClass properties using Dapper

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have a class called `Students`

```
    public class Students 
    {
     private string name ;
     private string age;
     private string adress;

    //Constructor 
    public Students (string name,string age,string adress)
    {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.adress=adress;
    }
  }
```

and a Query `myQuery` :

```
Select h.name 
b.age,
v.adress 
FROM Tb.Students h 
INNER JOIN db.tb_1 d 
ON h.id= d.id 
 INNER JOIN db.TB_2 v
 ON d.id = v.id
```

Now when I run this :

```
 Connection conn = new Connection();
        OracleConnection connection = conn.GetDBConnection();

 var studentsInfo= connection.Query<Students>(myQuery).ToList();
```

I noticed `studentsInfo` has results and row size is loaded but when I put the cursor on  `studentsInfo` , the properties , `Name` , `Age`, `Adress` are empty

What I am missing ? How to assign the result of the query to my properties so I can use them like that :

```
foreach ( var student in studentsInfo )
{
 console.writeline(sutdent.age);
}
```

Comment: That's a strange class you have got there.

Comment: Did you try to run that query with some management software for Oracle? And I can't stop myself to ask you. How many Ages a student is supposed to have?

Comment: @Steve Hello steve , the query is fully functional using the "classic" way of querying ( when I use oracle reader functionality) , I'm trying to implement Dapper so I wrap all my queries and benefit from Dapper amazing functionalities

Comment: There is a typo in the query text: you use an alias _b_ for the table where you retrieve the age field, but on the join statements there is an alias _d_ and no alias for _b_ If this is your real query then it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Steve It's a fictional query , just to describe my problem ....just to illustrate my problem

Comment: @napi15 the fun question is: does your fictional query demonstrate - when tested - the actual problem?

Comment: Unrelated note: you should prefer `AsList()` to `ToList()`

Comment: wait a sec... "the properties , Name , Age, Adress are empty" - there *aren't any* properties; there are *fields*: `name`, `age` and `adress` - are we seeing something different? is it possible that you have both fields and automatically implemented properties? i.e. `private string name; public string Name {get;set;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help, but it *looks like* what you have should work. I tend to work with SQL Server, but the ADO.NET layer is *mostly* the same, and I tried the following case:

```
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

public class Students
{
    private string name;
    private string age;
    private string adress;

    public Students(string name, string age, string adress)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.adress = adress;
    }
    public override string ToString() => $"{name}, {age}, {adress}";
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            const string myQuery = "select 'fred' as [name], '27' as [age], 'somewhere' as [adress]";
            var studentsInfo = connection.Query<Students>(myQuery).ToList();
            foreach(var student in studentsInfo)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked fine, outputting:

```
fred, 27, somewhere
```

So my main thoughts would be: does the query output what you think it outputs? Is the data what you think it is? Also: are you sure that `age` is a `string`?

Comment: Hello Marc, do I need to use "AS"  in every line of the query and it must be match the same name of the class properties and in the same order and type of my class properties?

Comment: @napi15 nope; that should be implicit in your example; I've only used that here to supply aliases to the columns, since the query I'm using doesn't actually talk to any tables

Comment: @napi15 I'm confused as to why you've marked this as the answer; as far as I can tell we've barely started to scratch the surface of what is actually happening in your case

Comment: It's because the example helped me and I  found my mistake :) I will illustrate my solution shortly once it's tested

Comment: @napi15 reality is that producing a *minimal repro* is a *fantastic tool* - often, when you do that: the thing you were expecting to fail: **works fine**. So then it is just a case of figuring out what is different between the minimal case and the real case :)

Comment: Yup , as I expected :) age was a number and not a string , documentation was wrong and I had to go to the database and match every field . In conclusion : The class must have the same number of fields as the query and the types must match while the name/aliases  are not important . Thank you Marc !

Comment: @napi15 if you have a failing example I'd be genuinely interested in seeing it - as a way to improve dapper (even if only by throwing an exception with a useful message in it)